# ExtJS loadData Method only load one row

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs-mvc

I know this issue should set idProperty config.

In my case, I have two metadata. One has unique id for each data but another one has the same id.

When I press the A button it works fine and load each data, press the B button it only load one row.

I tried to set Property for two views but wasn't working.

Is anyone help me this problem? Thanks!  [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/118d)

app.js

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',
  appFolder: 'app',
  autoCreateViewport: true,

  //stores: ['ListViewStore'],
  controllers: ['ListViewController'],

  launch: function() {

  }
});
```

Viewport

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.Viewport', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
  layout: 'border',

  requires: ['Fiddle.view.ListView', 'Fiddle.view.ButtonA',   'Fiddle.view.ButtonB'],

  items: [{
      region: 'north',
      xtype: 'toolbar',
      items: [{
          xtype: 'btna'
      }, {
          xtype: 'btnb'
      }]
  }, {
      region: 'center',
      xtype: 'listview',
  }]
});
```

view

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.ListView', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.listview',
  title: 'MVC Grid Sample',
  store: 'ListViewStore',
  height: 200,
  width: 400,

  initComponent: function() {
      var me = this;

      me.columns = [{
          header: 'track',
          dataIndex: 'track',
          flex: 1
      }, {
          header: 'title',
          dataIndex: 'title',
          flex: 1
      }, {
          header: 'album',
          dataIndex: 'album',
          flex: 1
      }, {
          header: 'length',
          dataIndex: 'duration',
          flex: 1
      }, {
          header: 'artist',
          dataIndex: 'artist',
          flex: 1
      }, {
          header: 'type',
          dataIndex: 'genre',
          flex: 1
      }, {
          header: 'rank',
          dataIndex: 'rank',
          flex: 1
      }];

      me.callParent(arguments);

  }
});
```

model

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.model.ListViewModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['track', 'title', 'album', 'duration', 'artist', 'rank', 'path', 'artwork', 'id', 'genre', 'album_artist', 'click_counting', 'last_play', 'amount', 'valuetype']
});
```

store

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.store.ListViewStore', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'Fiddle.model.ListViewModel',

  loadByBuffer: function(data) {
      var store = this;

      var newData = [];

      Ext.each(data, function(item) {
          newData.push([
          item['track'],
          // item['title'],
          (function() {
              if (item['valuetype'] === 3) {
                  if (item['album'] == '') {
                      return 'Unknown Album';
                  } else {
                      return item['album'];
                  }
              } else if (item['valuetype'] === 1) {
                  if (item['artist'] == '') {
                      return 'Unknown Artist';
                  } else {
                      return item['artist'];
                  }
              } else {
                  return item['title'];
              }
          })(),
          item['album'],
          item['duration'],
          item['artist'],
          // item['valuetype'],
          item['rank'],
          item['path'],
          item['artwork'],
          item['id'],
          item['genre'],
          item['album_artist'],
          item['click_counting'],
          item['last_play'],
          item['amount'],
          item['valuetype'], ]);
      });

      store.loadData(newData, true);

  }
});
```

controller

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.controller.ListViewController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  stores: ['ListViewStore'],

  init: function() {
      var me = this;

      me.control({
          'btna': {
              toggle: me.clickButtonA
          },
          'btnb': {
              toggle: me.clickButtonB
          },
      });

      me.clickButtonA(this, true);
  },

  clickButtonA: function(me, pressed) {
      var me = this;

      if (pressed !== true) {
          return;
      }

      var data = [{
          "valuetype": 4,
          "id": 81,
          "amount": -1,
          "duration": 290,
          "track": 14,
          "rank": 0,
          "click_counting": 0,
          "last_play": 0,
          "title": "Come Together",
          "path": "\/volume1\/Music\/Aerosmith - Rocks Donington 2014\/CD2\/04 Come Together.mp3",
          "genre": "79",
          "album_artist": "",
          "artist": "Aerosmith",
          "album": "Rocks Donington",
          "artwork": ""
      }, {
          "valuetype": 4,
          "id": 90,
          "amount": -1,
          "duration": 231,
          "track": 0,
          "rank": 0,
          "click_counting": 0,
          "last_play": 0,
          "title": "Freedom Fighter",
          "path": "\/volume1\/Music\/Aerosmith - Rocks Donington 2014\/CD1\/08 Freedom Fighter.mp3",
          "genre": "79",
          "album_artist": "",
          "artist": "Aerosmith",
          "album": "Rocks Donington",
          "artwork": ""
      }, {
          "valuetype": 4,
          "id": 117,
          "amount": -1,
          "duration": 199,
          "track": 0,
          "rank": 0,
          "click_counting": 0,
          "last_play": 0,
          "title": "Lord Don't Slow Me Down",
          "path": "\/volume1\/Music\/Oasis - Time Flies Greatest Hits 2CD [Bubanee]\/CD1\/11 - Lord Don't Slow Me Down.mp3",
          "genre": "Pop",
          "album_artist": "",
          "artist": "Oasis",
          "album": "Time Flies... 1994-2009 CD1",
          "artwork": "\/volume1\/Music\/Oasis - Time Flies Greatest Hits 2CD [Bubanee]\/CD1\/11 - Lord Don't Slow Me Down.mp3"
      }];

      me.getListViewStoreStore().removeAll();
      me.getListViewStoreStore().loadByBuffer(data);

  },

  clickButtonB: function(me, pressed) {
      var me = this;

      if (pressed !== true) {
          return;
      }

      var data = [{
          "valuetype": 3,
          "id": -1,
          "amount": 20,
          "duration": -1,
          "track": -1,
          "rank": -1,
          "click_counting": -1,
          "last_play": -1,
          "title": "",
          "path": "",
          "genre": "",
          "album_artist": "",
          "artist": "Aerosmith",
          "album": "Rocks Donington",
          "artwork": ""
      }, {
          "valuetype": 3,
          "id": -1,
          "amount": 13,
          "duration": -1,
          "track": -1,
          "rank": -1,
          "click_counting": -1,
          "last_play": -1,
          "title": "",
          "path": "",
          "genre": "",
          "album_artist": "",
          "artist": "Oasis",
          "album": "Time Flies... 1994-2009 CD1",
          "artwork": "\/volume1\/Music\/Oasis - Time Flies Greatest Hits 2CD [Bubanee]\/CD1\/05 - Stop Crying Your Heart Out.mp3"
      }, {
          "valuetype": 3,
          "id": -1,
          "amount": 14,
          "duration": -1,
          "track": -1,
          "rank": -1,
          "click_counting": -1,
          "last_play": -1,
          "title": "",
          "path": "",
          "genre": "",
          "album_artist": "",
          "artist": "Oasis",
          "album": "Time Flies... 1994-2009 CD2",
          "artwork": "\/volume1\/Music\/Oasis - Time Flies Greatest Hits 2CD [Bubanee]\/CD2\/04 - D'You Know What I Mean¿.mp3"
      }];

      me.getListViewStoreStore().removeAll();
      me.getListViewStoreStore().loadByBuffer(data);
  }

});
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate ids. That is the point of the id, it is supposed to uniquely identify that record.

Comment: I tried to change the idProperty before I load the data. When I press A button I set me.getModel().idProperty = 'id'  and press B button I set me.getModel().idProperty = 'title' . But this is not working.

Comment: You can't just change it on the fly like that. If you can't specify a valid id, then let Ext make one up for you (exclude it from your data).

Comment: How to let Ext make one up for me? Is there any samples or docs for refer?

Comment: As I said above, just exclude the id from the data.

Comment: I see. But I have another question. Can I specify different idProperty for different metadata?

Comment: You can only specify different `idProperty` for different stores.